# Has a dyadic logarithm been studied?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

Define a dyadic logarithm of an odd dyadic integer $a$ as the limit of $\frac{a^z-1}{z}$ for $z\to0$ in the dyadic sense. I can prove, I'm assuming it's also well known, that dyadic exponentiation makes sense. (This is not true in general for p-adic integers.) A definition that works is to define $a^z$ as the limit of $a_n^{z_m}$ where $a_n$ is a sequence of positive integers that converges to $a$ in the dyadic sense and similarly $z_m \to z$.

I also have a proof that what I'm calling the dyadic logarithm exists and has some algebraic properties, such as the dyadic logarithm of a product is the sum of the dyadic logarithms. The dyadic logarithm of $-1$ and $1$ are both $0$.

I wonder if there are any known properties or uses of this function. Maybe cryptographic, or fast binary multiplication? Or perhaps it's used to prove some number theoretic result?

Comment: Analysis on the $p$-adic numbers is a well-developed topic. Maybe https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387960173 would be a good place to begin your studies.

Comment: I know what a [dyadic fraction or rational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational) is, but what is an "odd dyadic integer" or "converges in the dyadic sense"

Comment: I think you're using "dyadic" to mean "$2$-adic" here? This is not a good convention; "dyadic" conventionally means an element of $\mathbb{Z} \left[ \frac{1}{2} \right]$.

Comment: I think Tim O’Meara used the word “dyadic” for $2$-adic, but that was a longish time ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is rather well known, especially to folks in the formal-group racket.

You’re dealing with the formal group $\mathscr M(x,y)=x+y+xy=(1+x)(1+y)-1$, the formal group associated to multiplication, or in fancier (but perhaps rather sloppy) language, the formal group of the multiplicative group scheme $\mathbf G_{\mathrm m}$.

I hope you see that my formula for $\mathscr M$ is just a recoordinatization of multiplication, with the neutral element moved from $1$ to $0$. Your construction of the logarithm, which is a homomorphism from $\mathscr M$ to the additive formal group $\mathscr A(x,y)=x+y$, is perfect. In fact, it can be expressed by the $p$-adically convergent power series, $-\sum_1^\infty(-x)^n/n$, which you know from Calculus, but with the $1+x$ replaced by $x$. A wonderful thing about it is that it remains convergent whenever you substitute for $x$ something that’s closer to $0$ than $1$ is: in technical terms, $\log(a)$ is convergent for all $a$ with $|a|_p<1$, equivalently $v_p(a)>0$. So, for instance, you can plug $\sqrt2$ in for $a$ in your $2$-adic logarithm, and get a good value.

Only one other thing to say for now, and that’s that you don’t need to consider all $z\to0$ in your formula, you can just take powers of $2$ (powers of $p$ in the general case).